# как сделать чтобы sep=", " чтобы не добавлял пробел, к первому символе

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня тут задания и я хочу решить её, там дано число n, к примеру у меня число 10 и нужно написать все числа из десяти увеличеваешме порядке типа так: 10: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9. И вот как сдлеать так чтобы после 10 и двое точие не ставилось запятая?

```
N = 10
A = [i for i in range(N)]
print(N,":", *A, sep=", ")
```

это мой код, и у меня выходитиь неправильно типа так:`10, :, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9`
а должно как там сверху. Только напишите так чтобы новичок понял, пожалуйста?

Answer (score 2):

Вижу несколько вариантов, первый например

можно разделить `print`ы на два

```py
N = 10
A = [i for i in range(N)]
print(N, end=": ")
print(*A, sep=", ")
```

про `end` можно почитать тут:  https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print

Другой вариант:

```py
N = 10
A = [str(i) for i in range(N)]
print(f"{N}: {', '.join(A)}")
```

тут, в список `A`, я добавляю не числа(`int`), а строки(**`string`**)

тут используется `f-строки` про них можно прочитать тут: https://realpython.com/python-f-strings/

также используется метод `.join`, который делает конкатенацию (объединение) строчных объектов находящихся в итерируемых объектах типа списков https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=join#str.join

Answer (score 1):

Есть f-строки. В них можно писать переменные, не закрывая кавычек, писать их в фигурных скобках Чтобы программа поняла, что строка именно f, перед ней нужно поставить букву f. Например:

```
s = 'Hello, '
print(f'{s} world!')
```

Выведет:

```
Hello, world!
```

Есть метод join. Он как бы "лепит" строку из списка, множества и т.д.. Сначала даётся разделитель, чем разделить элементы списка в строке. Потом ставится `.join(список из которого надо сделать строку)`
Получается вот так: `разделитель.join(список из которого надо сделать строку)`
Пример. Этот код:

```
print(' '.join([1, 2, 3]))
```

Выведет:

```
1 2 3
```

С Вашим случаем я предлагаю эти f-строки и метод join.
Нужны переменная `N` и список `A` в одной строке. Это f-строка.
Нужно вывести список через разделитель: запятую с пробелом. Это join.
Получается решение вот такое:

```
print(f'{N}: {", ".join(A)}')
```

Comment: Только в последнем примере будет ошибка, из-за того, что внутри одинарных кавычек открываются еще одни одинарные кавычки (в `{', '.join(a)}`). Их нужно заменить на двойные

Comment: @denisnumb я исправил)